# How to align text inside link to bottom corner?

Tags: html, css

I have a card that needs to be covered by link and have text at the bottom corner. Currently text is located at the top, how can I move it to the bottom while keeping link covering card?

```css
.card{
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
width: 200px;
height: 250px;
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
}

.card a {
color: red;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}

.card a:hover {
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
<p>Some description goes here</p>
<a href='#'>Read more</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually called *stretched link* (for example in [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/stretched-link/)) and it uses pseudo (`before`/`after`) elements which are `absolute` while the original element can be somewhere else.

To place link at the bottom of the card (without using `absolute` position) I've set `flex` to `.card` and `margin-top: auto` to `a`.

Something like this:

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.card a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: auto;
}

/* ↓↓ this is it ↓↓ */
.card a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
}

.card a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
  <p>Some description goes here</p>
  <a href='#'>Read more</a>
</div>
```